# adding pom file on svn repository maven

Tags: svn, maven-2

OK, so I am using maven to try to add a pom file to a svn repository:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:URL</connection>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>test</id>
        <name>new-test</name>
        <url>URL</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That's what my pom.xml file looks like currently; of course the URL is my url and the username and pass are my actual username and password

I am very confused on the commands I should use to upload this.  If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.  Also, I am not sure if my pom.xml file is configured correctly.

Comment: it's not very clear what you want to achieve - put this file under revision control in a SVN repository ? configure artifact deployment ? anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search reveals the documentation at the maven-scm-plugin site on apache.org [here](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html) and [here](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html).

Based on my understanding of Maven and a quick scan through these documents, you should probably be doing the following:

1. I think that you are missing a `connectionType` declaration in the `configuration` section for the plug-in.
2. I'm not sure what your use case is for hanging the plug-in off of the `install` goal.
3. Use `mvn scm:add` initially, to add the file(s) to your SVN workspace.
4. Use `mvn -Dmessage="<commit_log_here>" scm:checkin` to commit the changes to SVN.
5. Use `mvn scm:update` to pull updates from SVN.

Comment: ok so i changes my pom.xml file and it now looks like this, and added the username and pass to my settings.xml file. i dont understand what you mean by "mvn -Dmessage="<commit_log_here>" scm:checkin" specifically the commit_log_here part

Comment: @mark: The `message` property specified using `-Dmessage=` in the command-line call lets you input your SVN commit message as part of the execution.